# Should mining.notify.merkle_branches contain the coinbase transaction or not?

Tags: mining-pools, development, mining-technical-details, stratum

Okay I'm working on a new pool-server though got a question.

I'm using litecoin testnet right now to test stuff and here's a getblocktemplate() response I get;

```
{
"result": {
    "version": 2,
    "previousblockhash": "8a39d544ae4f46bab42358baa72d338dc8d4ed764fc0cc578c16d339bb2aac4e",
    "transactions": [],
    "coinbaseaux": {
        "flags": "062f503253482f"
    },
    "coinbasevalue": 5000000000,
    "target": "0000014e2c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "mintime": 1399898893,
    "mutable": [
        "time",
        "transactions",
        "prevblock"
    ],
    "noncerange": "00000000ffffffff",
    "sigoplimit": 20000,
    "sizelimit": 1000000,
    "curtime": 1399898982,
    "bits": "1e014e2c",
    "height": 271882
},
"error": null,
"id": 1
```

}

As you can see it doesn't contain any transactions.

So while building my mining.notify structure, should my merkle_branches contain the coinbase transaction (generation transaction) I created or not?

From [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22929/full-example-data-for-scrypt-stratum-client) my notification should be similar to this;

```
job_id = "b3ba"
prevhash = "7dcf1304b04e79024066cd9481aa464e2fe17966e19edf6f33970e1fe0b60277"
coinb1 = "01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff270362f401062f503253482f049b8f175308"
coinb2 = "0d2f7374726174756d506f6f6c2f000000000100868591052100001976a91431482118f1d7504daf1c001cbfaf91ad580d176d88ac00000000"
Merklebranches = [ 
    "57351e8569cb9d036187a79fd1844fd930c1309efcd16c46af9bb9713b6ee734", 
    "936ab9c33420f187acae660fcdb07ffdffa081273674f0f41e6ecc1347451d23"
    ]
version = "00000002"
nbits = "1b44dfdb"
ntime = "53178f9b"
clean_jobs = true// Not required for block, just for completeness
```

But as I got 0 transactions from litecoin-testnet network to carry, my resulting json would not contain any merkle_branches.

So should I include the coinbase transaction I generated?

Comment: getblocktemplate() takes an array of capabilities as argument, what are you passing there?

Comment: {"coinbasetxn", "workid", "coinbase/append"}